# Quasi-isometric quotients of finitely generated groups

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group, $S$ a finite symmetric system of generators of $G$, and let $H,K\subset G$ be subgroups. Then $S$ induces a metric on the quotients $G/H$ and $G/K$; for instance, for $a,b\in G$, the distance $d(aH,bH)$ is the minimum number of elements in $S$ whose product $w$ satisfies $waH=bH$.

I would like to know if there is an interesting characterization of when $G/H$ is (coarsely) quasi-isometric to $G/K$. For instance, if $f$ is an automorphism of the group $G$ such that $f(H)\cap K$ is finite and $f(S)=S$, then $f$ induces a quasi-isometry of $G/H$ to $G/K$. Are there other types of examples?

Comment: Such objects are called "Schreier graphs" and there is a vast literature about them. The sentence starting with "for instance" is incorrect (take $f$ to be the identity, $H=G$ and $K$ trivial, for instance).

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems I should have written that $f(H)\cap K$ has finite index in $f(H)$ and $K$.